# Error while printing Nodes in C?

Tags: c, structure, nodes

I am trying to print what I have in nodes but it says the following error

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:83:37: error: request for member 'emails' in something not a structure or union
printf("%s\n", tmpNodesUnique[l].emails);
^
```

I get the above error after I run the following code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Node *tmpNodesUnique[nodesCount];
    int uniqueFound = 0;
    tmpNodesUnique[0] = &tmpNodes[0];
    for (k=1; k<10; k++){
        if (strcmp(tmpNodesUnique[uniqueFound]->emails, tmpNodes[k].emails) != 0){
            tmpNodesUnique[++uniqueFound] = &tmpNodes[k];
        }
    }

    for (k=0; k<=uniqueFound; k++){
      tmpNodesUnique[k]->emails;
    }
    for(l = 0; l <= nodesCount; l++){
            printf("%s\n", tmpNodesUnique[l]->emails);
        }
```

Comment: Why not `printf("%s\n", tmpNodesUnique[l]->emails);` ?

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work. It throws SegFault

Comment: The statement `tmpNodesUnique[k]->emails;` inside the second `for` loop doesn't do anything. The third `for` loop goes from `l` values up to `nodesCount` but `tmpNodesUnique` is only valid in the range `0` to `nodesCount-1`. Also, in that `for` loop, are you sure `tmpNodesUnique[l]` has a valid value above `l == uniqueFound`?

Comment: What's in your array of pointers `tmpNodesUnique` ? Does individual elements of it points to any valid location/allocated space ?

Comment: The compiler error looks like its from gcc and if I remember correctly the specific code snippet that caused the error is not printed. I suspect the OP (erroneously) copy-pasted the code snippet under the compiler error in his post.

Comment: @pankrates good eye.  But, the error is related to the use of a `.` so I think it's compiled using a `.`

Comment: @KayakDave are you sure? Because lets assume he really needed to use `.` (i.e. the targeted variable was of type `struct`) then calling `->` on it would try to dereference a `struct` which is not a struct itself and this would explain the `request for member 'emails' in something not a structure`

Comment: @pankrates But also, the definition of `tmpNodesUnique` is of an array of pointers to structs (I'm assuming Node is a struct).  So `->` is appropriate.  Perhaps OP will enlighten us soon with his findings.

Comment: @KayakDave you are completely right. I guess the conclusion is, that our blind debugging is not really effective :) like you say if OP wants to solve this he needs to fork over more details

Answer (score 0):

Probably your struct `Node` is defined as

```
typedef struct {
    char *emails;
} Node;
```

This means if you want to print the member `emails` you will have to use `.` operator and not the `->` operator

```
for(l = 0; l <= nodesCount; l++){
   printf("%s\n", tmpNodesUnique[l].emails);
}
```

And as pointed out in the comments the following line does nothing, it is an incomplete statement

```
for (k=0; k<=uniqueFound; k++){
  tmpNodesUnique[k]->emails;
}
```

Additionally make sure you really want `k<=` instead of `k<` it looks suspicious as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not compiling the code you expect.

The error uses a `.` member operator for emails. While you have a `->` pointer operator in the code you show.  So the code is different (and the error is related to the dot as it's stating that it expects a structure or union member while you've clearly declared a pointer).